# How to debug battery drain during suspend/hibernation?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, battery, hibernate

I feel like battery drains as if it was on during suspend, and hibernation too.
Last time I run `sudo systemctl hibernate` it went down ~20% in 12 hours. I'm not sure how to debug it properly, because everything seems like working fine (fans and power leds off), and `dmesg` logs seems ok.

I'm running KDE Neon (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), and TLP on a Thinkpad T14. These are my current battery stats

```
➜ sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = active (data, thresholds)
tpacpi-bat = active (recalibrate)
tp-smapi   = inactive (ThinkPad not supported)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 5B10W139
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =     11
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  50500 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  50500 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  17110 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   5483 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold         =     40 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold          =     60 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   33.9 [%]
Capacity                                                    =  100.0 [%]
```

Here's a graph during hibernation,

[image]

And here's a dmesg output. Also, it seems last logs before hibernation are actually dumped when restored, is that the normal behavior, right?

```
Jan 18 19:23:35 t14 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 18 19:23:35 t14 systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Jan 18 19:23:35 t14 kernel: [10039.466766] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Jan 18 19:23:35 t14 wpa_supplicant[979]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 18 19:23:36 t14 kernel: [10039.818576] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 18 19:23:36 t14 kernel: [10039.818580] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 18 19:23:36 t14 kernel: [10039.818589] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: Zeroing 64bit base registers, expecting fault
Jan 18 19:23:36 t14 kernel: [10039.915837] PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Jan 18 19:23:36 t14 systemd-sleep[62005]: Suspending system...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.922851] Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.922855] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925720] OOM killer disabled.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925961] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925962] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925964] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x09c00000-0x09d00fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925967] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x09f00000-0x09f0cfff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925968] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xa4662000-0xa4662fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925968] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xa466f000-0xa4670fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925969] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xa467e000-0xa467ffff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925970] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xa4690000-0xa4690fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925970] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb9607000-0xb9697fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.925972] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xbd9de000-0xcc3fdfff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.926373] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xce000000-0xffffffff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.927165] PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps created
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10039.937078] PM: hibernation: Preallocating image memory
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10040.180058] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10040.320815] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10040.320818] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.233740] PM: hibernation: Allocated 1193825 pages for snapshot
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.233744] PM: hibernation: Allocated 4775300 kbytes in 3.29 seconds (1451.45 MB/s)
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.233745] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.235622] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.730415] [drm] free PSP TMR buffer
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.773134] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.779782] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.890060] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.890061] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.890062] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.932854] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.935533] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.940535] IRQ 99: no longer affine to CPU2
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.941607] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.946930] IRQ 35: no longer affine to CPU3
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.946951] IRQ 53: no longer affine to CPU3
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.946960] IRQ 67: no longer affine to CPU3
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.948013] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.952821] IRQ 103: no longer affine to CPU4
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.953894] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.959267] IRQ 31: no longer affine to CPU5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.959314] IRQ 58: no longer affine to CPU5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.959324] IRQ 65: no longer affine to CPU5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.960384] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.965252] IRQ 97: no longer affine to CPU6
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.965269] IRQ 104: no longer affine to CPU6
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.966322] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.972862] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.979057] smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.985915] smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.992696] smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.998454] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 202
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.998497] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 202
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.999716] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.006044] smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.013167] smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.019204] smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.026169] smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030332] PM: hibernation: Creating image:
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] PM: hibernation: Need to copy 1274984 pages
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] PM: hibernation: Normal pages needed: 1274984 + 1024, available pages: 2716051
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] PM: hibernation: free pages cleared after restore
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] ACPI: EC: EC started
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030339] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030401] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.030402] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.953880] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.031109] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.031699] CPU1 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.031749] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.031030] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.032254] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.032736] CPU2 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.032778] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.032067] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.033247] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.033729] CPU3 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.033769] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x4
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.033080] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.034566] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.035093] CPU4 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.035136] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.034365] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.035641] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.036170] CPU5 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.036215] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x6
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.035481] microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.036736] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.037315] CPU6 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.037474] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.036534] microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.037926] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.038551] CPU7 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.038612] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x8
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.037754] microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.039223] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.039954] CPU8 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.040020] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x9
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.039018] microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.040628] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.041325] CPU9 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.041483] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0xa
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.040432] microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.042095] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.043020] CPU10 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.043086] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10043.999677] microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.043705] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.044489] CPU11 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.044557] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0xc
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.006019] microcode: CPU12: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.045184] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.046018] CPU12 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.046088] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xd
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.044964] microcode: CPU13: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.046723] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.047592] CPU13 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.047662] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xe
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.019182] microcode: CPU14: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.048287] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.049175] CPU14 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.049241] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.048078] microcode: CPU15: patch_level=0x08600106
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.049888] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 3 idle states
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.050936] CPU15 is up
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.060443] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.094020] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.326052] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.326103] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.327725] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.327729] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328712] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328739] [drm] PSP is resuming...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328885] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328888] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328888] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.328891] usb usb7: root hub lost power or was reset
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.329188] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: Zeroing 64bit base registers, expecting fault
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.348785] [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf41fc00000 for PSP TMR
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.651720] usb 6-4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.652736] nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.676418] amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.676436] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.676466] amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.676489] amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.818576] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.818579] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.906631] usb 6-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.949140] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10044.975303] [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01000000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.162640] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.187978] [drm] Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.201258] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205121] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205177] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205482] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205485] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205487] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205489] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205490] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205492] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205494] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205495] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205497] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205499] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205501] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205502] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205504] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205505] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.205507] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.281754] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.281804] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.281961] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.281985] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.282090] PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps freed
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.282101] OOM killer enabled.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.282102] Restarting tasks ... 
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.283518] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.286639] done.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.286689] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287480] pcieport 0000:00:02.1: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 01] add_size 1000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287493] pcieport 0000:00:02.1: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 01] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287513] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287542] pcieport 0000:00:02.2: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 02] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287551] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287804] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287816] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04] add_size 1000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287820] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 04] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287829] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287839] pcieport 0000:00:02.6: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 05] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287846] pci_bus 0000:06: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287854] pcieport 0000:00:02.7: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06] add_size 1000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287856] pcieport 0000:00:02.7: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 06] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287913] pcieport 0000:00:02.1: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x430200000-0x4303fffff 64bit pref]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287923] pcieport 0000:00:02.2: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x430400000-0x4305fffff 64bit pref]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287932] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x430600000-0x4307fffff 64bit pref]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287955] pcieport 0000:00:02.6: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x430800000-0x4309fffff 64bit pref]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287963] pcieport 0000:00:02.7: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x430a00000-0x430bfffff 64bit pref]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287975] pcieport 0000:00:02.1: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287977] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.287980] pcieport 0000:00:02.7: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.288391] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.3 build 0 week 24 2017
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.289824] PM: hibernation: hibernation exit
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290140] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290363] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 1
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290367] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290368] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290369] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290369] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290371] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 kernel: [10045.290379] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 bluetoothd[1327]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd-sleep[62005]: System resumed.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 bluetoothd[1327]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1740]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Daily apt download activities being skipped.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Daily apt upgrade and clean activities being skipped.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rotate log files being skipped.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Daily man-db regeneration being skipped.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 fwupdmgr[62420]: Updating lvfs
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Succeeded.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Finished Hibernate.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Reached target Hibernate.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Jan 19 18:24:44 t14 systemd[1]: Stopped target Hibernate.
```

*EDIT*: sometimes also happens at shutdown. ~15% drain in 17 hours. This time touchpad wasn't working after boot. Here's the dmesg output, https://0bin.net/paste/vASyBPz6#RkziBQVQkShueB9Km3tWDtCvXZWY7YgdckGD8LVyw84

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what suspend actually is, but in my case, at least one of the lights is blinking while it is suspended.  Also, by suspending, we have the ability to turn it back on quickly by opening up the lid.  So, I think the battery is being drained during suspension.  Is it not normally?

Comment: yes, suspension should drain battery slowly, not sure what are normal values. However, in my example, I hibernate (suspend to disk + shutdown)

Comment: I see what you mean!  Guess this isn't my area of expertise, but I reckon for suspension, it doesn't depend purely on software.  I think it would also depend on the battery?  Perhaps a newer battery would "behave" better than an older one?

Comment: yeah, that's true, but actually the laptop and battery are new. if you check at `tlp-stat` output above, there's just 11 cycles, and capacity 100%

Comment: If also happens on hibernate/shutdown then is a hardware issue and therefore not related the OS. Probably you have a malfunction battery. I would extract it and measure how voltage drops over time.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting, but I am trying to debug the drain as well. How did you get the battery during hibernation readings for that graph?

Comment: hi, I think that's just an interpolation between the two points before and after hibernation. if you're debugging a Thinkpad AMD, there's a whole [topic](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/T14-AMD-battery-drain-in-standby-Linux/m-p/5037674) in Lenovo's forums

Answer (score 0):

Suspend will drain the battery because the memory needs to be refreshed even though the CPU is off. Hibernation should not drain the battery.

The flashing LEDs during suspend are normally controlled by an embedded controller that runs closed source proprietary code and can't be disabled. However, the power consumed for this is very low and probably not easily measurable.

One possible thing to try and reduce power consumption during hibernate or suspend is to unload drivers and suspend and reload them on resume just in case the driver does not do power management properly.  But one needs to go through all the loaded drivers methodically one by one and measure power consumption during suspend and this can take quite a bit of time and effort.  Even then it may not help.

Comment: right, even if CPUs are off some device might be draining if it is not properly unloaded right? that should be noticed in dmesg output. I also wonder why suspend/hibernation logs are delayed until restored. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

If your battery is still draining even while shutdown, it's very possible the battery could be going bad. If you haven't yet, try replacing the battery and seeing if you have the same quick draining effect.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have a ThinkPad, and I guess that it would have a native battery management software that it is not supported in Ubuntu (I have an IdeaPad)...

Luckily, there is an extension for Lenovo users:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2992/ideapad/

If supported, it will help your laptop to manage the power more efficiently, including hibernation and 'conservation mode' for longer battery life.

Hope that helps and that works for your laptop.